# C# Creating a local string variable in linq - lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

When writing a lambda - method syntax, I would like a function that for all classes that have attributes, prints each class name and its attributes.

```
 var x1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetTypes()
   .Select(type => type
      .GetCustomAttributes(false)
      .Select(attribute => type.Name + " - " + attribute.ToString())
      .ToList())
   .ToList();

 x1.ForEach(type => type.ForEach(str => Console.WriteLine(str)));
```

Output:

```
<ClassName> - <ProgramName>.<AttributeName>
<ClassName> - <ProgramName>.<AttributeName>
<>c__DisplayClass6 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
```

I understand that the last line in the output, is because using a local lambda expression variable.

How to avoid displaying the last line?

Comment: you can check like if (type.IsDefined (typeof (CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)) and skip it.

Comment: thanks!  It Works.

Comment: glad to help you !

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a type has a `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` like that:

```
var x1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null)
   .Select(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(false)
      .Select(attribute => type.Name + " - " + attribute.ToString())
  .ToList()).ToList();
```

If a type is created by the compiler (instead of the developer), that type has an `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`. The `Where()` in above code filters out all types that have this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetTypes()
   .Where(type => !type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)))
   .Select(type => type
      .GetCustomAttributes(false)
      .Select(attribute => type.Name + " - " + attribute.ToString())
      .ToList())
   .ToList();

 x1.ForEach(type => type.ForEach(str => Console.WriteLine(str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment.

```
var x1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
           .GetTypes()
           .Where(type=>!type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false))
           .Select(type => type
              .GetCustomAttributes(false)
              .Select(attribute => type.Name + " - " + attribute.ToString())
              .ToList())
           .ToList();
            x1.ForEach(type => type.ForEach(Console.WriteLine));
```

You may check this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2007/04/27/correct-usage-of-the-compilergeneratedattribute-and-the-generatedcodeattribute/). It tell you about correct usage of CompilerGeneratedAttribute.